# Hibernate @OneToOne mapping with a @Where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Will this work -

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "type_id")
@Where(clause = "type_name = OBJECTIVE")
public NoteEntity getObjectiveNote() {
  return objectiveNote;
}
```

This is what I am trying to do - get the record from table `note` whose `type_id` is the `id` of the current object and `type_name` is `OBJECTIVE`.

I can't get the above mapping to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "OBJECTIVE" is it constant or an attribute?

Comment: You need to show `NoteEntity`. Also, try configuring `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in order to see what's in the SQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This just plain does not work, sorry :(  You will need to do it as one to many and live with getting a collection with a single element.

If you really want it to work this way, you can trick hibernate by storing both the foreign key ID and the type_name in a join table and telling it that both columns make up the foreign key.

Comment: Ok, how? Option #2

Comment: @Affe i can confirm that first option by changing the object to a list and doing onetomany(even if the design is onetoone), then getting a single element works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can achieve this by specifying `@OneToOne` without any `@Where`, but putting `@Where` on the referenced entity class. I tested this on Hibernate 4.3.11.

This works if you don't care about any entity objects that do not match your `@Where`.

If you *do* care about other entities, you can probably create a subclass entity, put `@Where` on it and join that subclass. But I have not tested this scenario.

Comment: putting where on the subclass does not seem to work when the join column is specified in the base class

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `JoinColumnsOrFormulas` annotation.

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "type_id")),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula =
        @JoinFormula(value = "OBJECTIVE", referencedColumnName = "type_name"))
})
public NoteEntity getObjectiveNote() {
  return objectiveNote;
}
```

This should produce join condition even with additional filtering for `type_name = OBJECTIVE`.