# Hibernate annotation for single select object (with where) instead of on-to-many collection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, max, hibernate-annotations

Currently we have a class that looks something like that (depersonalised and non-relevant parts removed):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN_TABLE")
public class MainTable extends AbstractTable {

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mainTable")
  @OrderBy("CREATED_ON DESC")
  private Set<MainTableState> states;

  ...

  public MainTableState getActiveState(){
    if(this.states == null || this.states.isEmpty()){
      return null;
    }
    MainTableState latest = states.iterator().next();
    // The reason we use this for-loop, even though we have the @OrderBy annotation,
    // Is because we can later add states to this list, which aren't automatically ordered
    for(MainTableState state : states){
      if(state.getCreatedOn() != null && latest.getCreatedOn() != null &&
           state.getCreatedOn().after(latest.getCreatedOn()){
        latest = state;
      }
    }
    return latest;
  }

  ...
}
```

So currently it will retrieve all MainTableStates from the DB by default, and if we need the activeState we use the for-loop method. Obviously this is pretty bad for performance. Currently we don't use this list at all (the purpose was to have a history of states, but this has been postponed to the future), but we do use the `getActiveState()` method quite a bit, mostly to show a String inside of the `MainTableState`-class in the UI.

In addition, even if we would always use a `TreeSet` and keep it sorted so we won't need the loop but only need `states.iterator().next()` instead, it will still initialize the list of states. With some heavy performance testing we had more than 1 million `MainTableState`-instances when it crashed with an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

So, we want to change it to the following instead:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN_TABLE")
public class MainTable extends AbstractEntity {

  @???
  private MainTableState activeState;

  ...

  public MainTableStates getActiveState(){
    return activeState;
  }

  ...
}
```

So, my question, what should I put at the `@???` to accomplish this? I'm assuming I need the `@Formula` or something similar, but how can I say to hibernate it should return a `MainTableState` object? I've seen `@Formula` being used with `MAX` for a date, but that was to get that date-property, not get an entire object based on that max date.

---

After *@user2447161*'s suggestion I've used a `@Where`-annotation, which does indeed help to reduce the Collection size to 1 (sometimes), but I have two more related questions:

1. How to use `@OnToMany` and `@Where` but get a single object, instead of a list of objects of size one? Is this even possible? [Here in a answer from December 2010 it is stated it isn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383070/hibernate-onetoone-mapping-with-a-where-clause/4383145#4383145) Has this been fixed somewhere in the last six years?
2. How to deal with the random alias in the where clause? I could do something like this:

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mainTable")
   @Where(clause = "CREATED_ON = (SELECT MAX(mts.CREATED_ON) FROM MAIN_TABLE_STATES mts WHERE mts.FK_MAIN_ID = ???.MAIN_ID)")
   private Set states; // TODO Get single object instead of collection with size 1

The problem with is that `???` is a random alias generated by hibernate (sometimes it's `this_`, sometimes it's something along the lines of `mainTable_1_`, etc.). How to set this alias for the entire query to the DB to use it here? I also tried `MAIN_TABLE.MAIN_ID` instead which doesn't work, and with no alias it also doesn't work because it uses the `MainTableState`-alias instead of `MainTable`-alias (like this below).

```
from
    MAIN_TABLE this_ 
left outer join
    MAIN_TABLE_STATUSES mainstat2_ 
        on this_.main_id=mainstat2_.fk_main_id 
        and (
            mainstat2_.created_on = (
                SELECT
                    MAX(mts.created_on) 
            FROM
                MAIN_TABLE_STATUSES mts 
            WHERE
-- mainstat2_.main_id should be this_.main_id instead here:
                mts.fk_main_id = mainstat2_.main_id
        )
    )
```

Comment: Unless you have an insane amount of rows, no indices and/or very strict requirements when it comes to performance, I can't really see that this will be a performance issue. With modern computers a for loop is usually a matter of nano seconds, and loading a set rather than a single row should be negligible.. Also, make sure that the list is eager-fetched when it is used, there is considerable overhead with lazy-loading (probably a number of magnitude larger than the actual looping..)

Comment: @Tobb I've added another line to the question. The for-loop isn't the main issue, it's the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` with more than 1 million `MainTableState`-instances. That is the main reason why we want to just save a single active-state, instead of entire collections (which are currently not used).

Comment: Maybe check @where and Filters ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365285/hibernate-limit-query-with-one-to-many.
Or make your own DTO out of a custom query...

Answer (score 0):

Well, regarding your question #2, as it looks like you need a quick solution with minimal impact in your existing code, this may be acceptable:  you can use an [Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) to deal with the alias and generate the right sql statement. Do this:

1. use a unique string as alias placeholder in your @Where clause, for instance:
   `...WHERE mts.FK_MAIN_ID = ${MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS}.MAIN_ID...`
2. if your application doesn't have one yet, create an  Interceptor class extending `EmptyInterceptor` and configure it as a SessionFactory interceptor
3. override the `onPrepareStatement` method to replace the placeholder with the alias found after 'from MAIN_TABLE' with something like this:

   `public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
       String modifiedSql = sql;
       if (sql.contains("${MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS}")) {
           String mainTableAlias = findMainTableAlias(sql);
           modifiedSql = sql.replace("${MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS}", mainTableAlias);
       }
       return modifiedSql;
   }`

Be aware that this method will be called for every sql statement that hibernate generates in your application.

Additionaly, your @Where clause only works properly when a join is used, so you should set the fetch mode explicitly adding
    `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`
to the `states` property to avoid that hibernate may use the select mode.